# VBA Run Time Error 1004 AutoFilter method of Range class Failed

Tags: vba, excel, macros, runtime-error

I hope you can help. I am getting the error Run Time Error 1004 AutoFilter method of Range class Failed

When I run my code `Public Sub TestThis()`, the funny thing is It works perfectly by itself, but when I put it into the other code and call it, it gives the error Run Time Error 1004 AutoFilter method of Range class Failed

The error is happening on this line

```
.Range("A:K").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Like I said when not called and run by itself no problem when called it bugs. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code is below.

```
Sub Open_Workbook_Dialog()

Dim my_FileName As Variant
Dim my_Workbook As Workbook

  MsgBox "Pick your CRO file" '<--| txt box for prompt to pick a file

  my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*") '<--| Opens the file window to allow selection

  If my_FileName <> False Then
    Set my_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=my_FileName)

    Call TestThis

    Call Filter(my_Workbook) '<--|Calls the Filter Code and executes

  End If
End Sub

Public Sub Filter(my_Workbook As Workbook)
  Dim rCountry As Range, helpCol As Range
  Dim wb As Workbook
  With my_Workbook.Sheets(1) '<--| refer to data worksheet
    With .UsedRange
      Set helpCol = .Resize(1, 1).Offset(, .Columns.Count) '<--| get a "helper" column just at the right of used range, it'll be used to store unique country names in
    End With

   With .Range("A1:Y" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) '<--| refer to its columns "A:Y" from row 1 to last non empty row of column "A"
            .Columns(11).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=helpCol, Unique:=True '<-- call AdvancedFilter on 11th column of the referenced range and store its unique values in "helper" column
            Set helpCol = Range(helpCol.Offset(1), helpCol.End(xlDown)) '<--| set range with unique names in (skip header row)
            For Each rCountry In helpCol '<--| iterate over unique country names range (skip header row)
                .AutoFilter 11, rCountry.Value2 '<--| filter data on country field (11th column) with current unique country name
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell other than header ones has been filtered...
                    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add '<--... add new Workbook
                        wb.SaveAs Filename:=rCountry.Value2 '<--... saves the workbook after the country
                            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
                               ActiveSheet.Name = rCountry.Value2  '<--... rename it
                           .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1") 'copy data for country under header
                           Sheets(1).Range("A1:Y1").WrapText = False 'Takes the wrap text off
                           ActiveWindow.Zoom = 55
                         Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit 'Autofits the column
                    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True '<--... saves and closes workbook
                End If
            Next
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove autofilter and show all rows back
    End With
    helpCol.Offset(-1).End(xlDown).Clear '<--| clear helper column (header included)
End Sub

Public Sub TestThis()
Dim wks As Worksheet

Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

With wks
.AutoFilterMode = False
.Range("A:K").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlFilterValues
.Range("A:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.Color = 65535
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if `Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)` gives you the sheet you want, **from the workbook you want**. `ThisWorkbook.` statement refers to workbook, where macro (VBA project) is placed. Maybe you need change it to

```
Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
```

or pass `my_Workbook` to  `TestThis()` macro.

Comment: Limak: Awesome stuff my friend I don't how I missed that. A fresh set of eyes can do wonders. Thank you so much for this much respect from Dublin :-)